# Is it possible to add an item to mobile context menu when a text is selected in any app?

Tags: android, contextmenu

I want to add an option to context menu everywhere in mobile, similar to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imgur-uploader/lcpkicdemehhmkjolekhlglljnkggfcf?hl=en but for mobile across all apps.

Comment: This is what you are looking for: [Creating custom Text Selection actions with ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999)

Comment: Hey, thanks for this,it worked. Is there something similar for ios as well?